# Android , thread usage

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

My program is sending data to web server when accelerometer datas exceed the threshold which determined by me. So , I used thread mechanism for sending operation :

```
if( threshold is exceeded )
    thread_send .start();
```

But this usage cause "Thread Already Used" error. So I used a method that I think is bad is below and it works :

```
if( threshold is exceeded ) {
    thread_send = new Thread(this);
    send_thread.start();
}
```

New thread is created at every turn. Does that usage cause negative results? (For example, memory problem or performance problem etc.)

What are your suggestions?

Editted :

My program should send data to web server very often. The most important thing is working correctly.So slow working is allowable , as long as the program can't stop suddenly..

I used ExecutorService in line with your suggestions :

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

........    

if( threshold is exceeded ) {
   threadExecutor.execute(this);
}
```

But errors occured : RecejtedExecutionException.. 
[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: It will depend on factors like how often you send data, and how quickly you need to send it. For example, if you can afford to wait for a while, you might be able to keep the data in memory and send it all in one go when the app is finished. If you send data almost continuously, then a single thread that does multiple work, or thread pool such as one created by `Executors.newXXX` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The second code looks correct, though it may slow it down if too many threads are running in parallel. Depending on the application, it might be appropriate to have threads run one-at-a-time in a queue, using [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Answer (score 0):

One idea is creating a singleton like service that runs the thread, that way if one isn't running, then it starts one, otherwise it ignores it.

If you want multiple running at the same time, what you have is correct. Remember a thread can only be ran once per new Thread()